# Invalid Authenticity Token in form even though it's present

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having an issue with a form that returns

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

still my params have it present

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"ovSc3ZMU8fGTkHileMaQpchm2bAjNz+TO46xTfUFHqP2wckumC8tMefgUQ/UIHRb1323o9YeSDfQMxTAQhDdgg==", "driver_request"=>{"accepted"=>"true"}, "commit"=>"Accepted", "controller"=>"driver_requests", "action"=>"update", "driver_id"=>"1", "id"=>"40"}
```

the form looks like this, and have a hidden token field present, when I inspect it:

```
    <%= form_for([current_driver, driver_request]) do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :accepted, value: true %>
      <%= f.submit 'Accepted', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <% end %>
```

where I think the issue might come from is the way I render the form. I'm using rails 5 and they now let you access `ApplicationController` and I'm calling on a partial that is a modal, with the form in it - like this:

```
 ApplicationController.renderer.render(partial: 'driver_requests/driver_request', locals: { driver_request: request, current_driver: request.driver })
```

now obviously I don't want to disable authenticity tokens, so I'm trying to find a way to debug this - but frankly I'm very unsure on how to fix this - as the token is actually present.

**Update: temporary solution:**

I got this working by making the form use AJAX. I think it has to do with the fact that I render a partial from `ApplicationController` and that the partial is thus not able to get the `csrf_meta_tag`. Still, this is just speculation.

Comment: And where do you call Application controller?

Comment: I'm calling it in an ActiveJob